# Identify library calls in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, dll, gdb, x86-64

Given the following assembly I obtained from GDB, is there any way to determine what function is being imported? The GDB comments tell us that we are importing `puts`, but how would I figure this out statically?

```
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
   0x00000000004003b8 <+0>: jmpq   *0x2004a2(%rip)        # 0x600860 <puts@got.plt>
   0x00000000004003be <+6>: pushq  $0x0
   0x00000000004003c3 <+11>:    jmpq   0x4003a8
```

Comment: Is your question about which *library*, or which *function* ? The former is impossible to answer statically, because the answer can change at runtime.

Comment: I meant which function, not which library - thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is somewhat processor- and OS-specific, different ELF implementations may do it in different ways.

For x64 Linux (and most other implementation that use PLT), you can inspect the *dynamic relocations* of the ELF:

```
> readelf -dr file.elf
...
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x700 contains 17 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000602018  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __strcat_chk + 0
000000602020  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 free + 0
000000602028  000400000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 clock + 0
000000602030  000500000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 fclose + 0
```

The "Offset" is the address of the pointer in the `.got.plt` section which is being used by the `jmpq` instructions in the stubs of the `.plt` section.

Initially that pointer points to the dynamic loader stub, which will resolve the address on the first call (using info from the relocation entries) and will patch the pointer in the GOT to the resolved address so that it jumps directly to the target on next calls.

See [this post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/11/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries-on-x64/) (and [previous one](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/)) for a more extensive explanation of this mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `objump`:

```
objdump -d foo
```

And you can pipe `objdump` output to `grep`.

```
objdump -d foo | grep -A 3 'puts@plt>:'
```

The number after `-A` controls how many lines (instructions) are printed after the match.